# Resultant of $x^n-a^n$ and $x^m-b^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**It is stated**, that

> the resultant of polynomials $x^n-a^n$ and $x^m-b^m$ equals
>   $$
> \mathrm{Res}(x^n-a^n,x^m-b^m) = (-1)^n(b^{nm/d}-a^{nm/d})^d,
> $$
>   where $d = GCD(n,m)$.

**My attempts:** first note that 
$$\mathrm{Res}(x^m-b^m, x^n-a^n) = (-1)^{nm}\mathrm{Res}(x^n-a^n, x^m-b^m)$$
$$=(-1)^{nm}(-1)^n(b^{nm/d}-a^{nm/d})^d = (-1)^{nm}(-1)^n(-1)^d(a^{nm/d}-b^{nm/d})^d$$
and since $(-1)^{nm}(-1)^n(-1)^d = (-1)^{m}$ we can without loss of generality consider $n\geq m$.

Now let $m=1$. In this case resultant has the form $\mathrm{Res}(x^n-a^n,x-b)$. If we use formula $\mathrm{Res}(f,g)=(-1)^{nm}g_0^n f(\beta_1)\ldots f(\beta_m)$, where $g_0$ - leading coefficient of $g$ and $\beta_1\ldots \beta_m$ - roots of $g$, we get:
$$
\mathrm{Res}(x^n-a^n,x-b) = (-1)^{n}(b^n-a^n),
$$
which corresponds with the general equation. The idea here is to go induction on $m$, but how do I reduce right side leaving left side intact?

I tried to divide with remainder and use the formula 
$$
f=gp+r \implies \mathrm{Res}(f,g)=g_0^{\deg f - \deg r}R(r,g),
$$
but this got me nowhere.